# VBA XML Import - Issue with Headers

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I currently have a number (currently 4) separate functions to import data from XML webpages into an Excel worksheet. It works perfectly fine, except the tables always add in headers.

```
Sub XMLImportMINS()
 On Error GoTo Errorcatch
 ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:= _
 "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=39&typeid=40&typeid=25595&typeid=25605&typeid=25600&typeid=25599&typeid=25590&typeid=25601&typeid=25603&typeid=25588&typeid=25594&typeid=25602&typeid=25598&typeid=25606&typeid=2367&typeid=2348&typeid=11399&typeid=33539&typeid=2346&typeid=12836&usesystem=30000142", _
  ImportMap:=Nothing, _
  Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("ISKValues!$H$4")
Exit Sub

Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Quite a simple script just to retrieve the data stored on the webpage from eve-central.com. It will input a table with as many rows as the typeIDs (in this case 25) but it will add a header at the top.

The header then means to import data for the four tables I need to space them 1 apart each and ends up with rather messy looking headers halfway through. I can manually edit them out and refresh the tables, but the connections mess up after restarting excel (which is why I went from manual import to VBA based import).

I am unsure how to edit table properties using Excel VBA but I presume I can separate them by 1 in the initial import, edit the headers off the table and move the tables all up by however much to have them placed properly?

Comment: Are you trying to import 4 different sets of data into one result set?

Comment: That would be preferable, but atm I have it set to import it into 4 result sets and just line them up one after another due to URL limits (approximately 2k or so URL characters).

Comment: I found how to use ListObjects.ShowHeaders to remove headers but am unsure how to automatically move the table.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out, but it's pretty crazy how there's nothing that I can find to make this easy to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to post an incomplete answer like this, but this is turning out to be a ton of work.

Basically, what I was thinking you could do is to load multiple queries from the API (to the limit you mention of 25 IDs each query) into an MSXML2 object. Then you can combine the results you're looking for within the code, and then export to the worksheet. I have everything working except exporting to the worksheet (proving to be exhausting to code).

Here's what I got to work (**NOTE** be sure to set a reference to Microsoft XML v6.0):

```
Public Sub getXML()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iLast As Long

    Dim xmlFirst As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmlFirst = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim xmlSecond As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xmlSecond = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    ' grab the first set of data
    xmlFirst.validateOnParse = True
    xmlFirst.Load "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=25595&typeid=25605&typeid=25600&typeid=25599&typeid=25590&typeid=25601&typeid=25603&typeid=25588&typeid=25594&typeid=25602&typeid=25598&typeid=25606&typeid=2367&typeid=2348&typeid=11399&typeid=33539&typeid=2346&typeid=12836&usesystem=30000142"

    ' grab the second set of data
    xmlSecond.validateOnParse = True
    xmlSecond.Load "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=39&typeid=40"

    ' wait for the XML to load into the objects
    While (xmlFirst.readyState <> 4 Or xmlSecond.readyState <> 4)
        DoEvents
    Wend

    ' combine the second query into the first
    iLast = xmlSecond.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes.Length - 1
    For i = 0 To iLast
        xmlFirst.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).appendChild xmlSecond.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0)
    Next

End Sub
```

The harder part is actually getting this data to the worksheet. I couldn't figure out an easy way to do that. I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631544/quick-convert-xml-to-excel), but I think it's more complicated than this.

By the way, this part of the code:

```
xmlFirst.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).appendChild xmlSecond.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0)
```

I was able to figure that out by looking at the Locals window and dig down into the nodes.

I hope this helps you at least combine the data into a single source.

Comment: Thank you dude, I shall look it over and try it out.

Atm I'm just likely to leave it with the headers or spaces in between and just use vlookup.

Comment: Sure thing. The alternative solution you mention should work fine. Good luck! Let me know how it goes!