# Protractor test results in Excel sheet

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I am new to testing. I am writing e2e test cases for my angular application using protractor. How to generate reports for test cases in Excel sheets.
Can any one please explain.

```
Protractor@2.1.0
jasmine@1.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, *there is no protractor excel reporter built at the moment.*

As a workaround, you can use `junit` or `html` reporters and convert the results into excel separately, see:

- [jasmine-reporters](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters)
- [protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter)

Comment: thanks for reply. I have tried jasmine-reports but it is getting in xml format, but I want them in excel sheets.

Comment: @N123 that's what I'm saying. There is no excel reporter made, you have to handle it yourself. Dump the results to junit xml or html and convert to excel.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to convert into excel

Comment: @N123 well, I haven't personally done this, but quick google search revealed: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-an-xml-file-into-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-this-technique/6163451/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631544/quick-convert-xml-to-excel or etc.

Comment: You probably have at least 3 other options: use a free converter to convert xml to CSV (http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm,) download a free one from somewhere, or write a converter yourself.